# Write this equation

Tags: equations, delimiters

I want to write this equation in this way down but I have been unsuccessful.
How can I improve this codes in order to get the equation below?

```
\[ DeltaC{t} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 
-1.40- 0.588w_{t-1} - 0.5351\DeltaC_{t-1}+ 0.169\DeltaBC_{t-1} & \mbox{ if $w_{t-1}<- 0.62$} \\
-1.40 - 0.588w_{t-1} - 0.5351\DeltaC_{t-1} + 0.169\DeltaBC_{t-1} & \mbox{$w_{t-1}>0.62$}
\end{array}
\right. \]
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is this for? (Also, you only have one column for the `array`; remove an `l`.)

Comment: It is a regression. My goal is to write the equation in the same form that the second one below without number in parenthesis. I want to write the equation without those in parentesis. Please just consider the  first one and tell me how it is working!.

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't provided a definition for `\DeltaC` or `\DeltaBC` in your post; please expand it into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so someone can tell you what's actually going wrong.

Answer (score 9):

I think you want `cases` from `amsmath`. Also, instead of `\mbox`, it is better to use `\text`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ 
  DeltaC{t} = \begin{cases}
    -1.40- 0.588w_{t-1} - 0.5351\Delta_{t-1}+ 0.169\Delta_{t-1} & \text{if $w_{t-1}<- 0.62$} \\
    -1.40 - 0.588w_{t-1} - 0.5351\Delta_{t-1} + 0.169\Delta_{t-1} & \text{$w_{t-1}>0.62$}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Since your equation is too long, I have split it in to two lines and added some space adjustments and fine tuning by Enrico. (Thanks to egreg).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\DeltaC}[1]{%
  \Delta\pi^{\textnormal{Services}}_{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\DeltaBC}[1]{%
  \Delta\pi^{\textnormal{Goods}}_{#1}%
}


\begin{document}

\[
\DeltaC{t} = \begin{cases}
  -0.03_{(0.08)} - 0.08_{(0.05)} + 0.09_{(0.18)} \DeltaC{t-1} \\
    \qquad{} + 0.12_{(0.03)}\DeltaBC{t-1} + u_{2t}, & \text{if $w_{t-1}<-0.62$,} \\[2ex]
  0.38_{(0.15)} - 0.12_{(0.04)} + 0.40_{(0.07)} \DeltaC{t-1} \\
    \qquad{} + 0.18_{(0.06)}\DeltaBC{t-1} + u_{2t}, & \text{if $ w_{t-1} > 2.2$,}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your response was very helpful,particularly the first option(with cases), to write this equation. Thanks

Comment: @ntamjoachille Glad that was useful. You can also accept answers and upvote them if they are useful :)

Comment: where can i upvote?

Answer (score 3):

Your equation actually only has one column (but it has two rows).  But in this case, it would be better to use the `cases` environment from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\Delta\pi_t^\text{Services} =
\begin{cases}
  -0.03_{0.08} - 0.08_{0.05} + 0.09_{0.18} \Delta\pi_{t-1}^\text{Services} + 0.12_{0.03} \Delta\pi_{t-1}^\text{Goods} + u_{2t} & w_{t-1} \leq 2.2 \\
   0.38_{0.15} - 0.12_{0.04} + 0.40_{0.07} \Delta\pi_{t-1}^\text{Services} + 0.18_{0.06} \Delta\pi_{t-1}^\text{Goods} + u_{2t} & w_{t-1} > 2.2
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Harish       
\[
DeltaCanada_{t} =  \begin{cases} 
                                    -1.40(0.02) - 0.58(1.5e-8)w_{t-1} - 0.53(0.14)\DeltaCanada_{t-1}+ 0.169(0.03)\DeltaBritishColumbia_{t-1} & \text{ if $w_{t-1} \leq 0.62$} \\
                                    -0.73(0.76) - 0.15(0.17)w_{t-1} - 0.99(2.5e-7)\DeltaCanada_{t-1} + 0.24(0.13) \DeltaBritishColumbia_{t-1} & \text{$w_{t-1}>0.62$}
                                      \end{cases}
                        \ ]

Comment: @ntamjoachille What?

Comment: I have tried to write it in a clearer way. You can see it in this link:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153871/writing-equations-in-miktex?noredirect=1#comment351487_153871

Comment: @ntamjoachille It is certainly not clear to anyone who doesn't know the topic of your work.  Please do not post duplicate questions like this; if the answers here don't actually answer your original question, say so *here* — not in a new post.

Comment: i have combined  all your suggestions on my latex codes and now it is working.

Comment: @ntamjoachille Then please accept the answer that was more helpful.

Comment: @ntamjoachille You should comment on his answer instead, then.