# Writing equations in Miktex

Tags: equations, delimiters

I need some help to ease me understanding this equation. I have tried to write but Miktex is bugging. Can someone tell me how to improve it in order to let it working?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\[
DeltaCanada_{t} =  \begin{cases} 
   -1.40(0.02) - 0.58(1.5e-8)w_{t-1} - 0.53(0.14)\DeltaCanada_{t-1}+ 0.169(0.03)\DeltaBritishColumbia_{t-1} & \text{ if $w_{t-1} \leq 0.62$} \\
   -0.73(0.76) - 0.15(0.17)w_{t-1} - 0.99(2.5e-7)\DeltaCanada_{t-1} + 0.24(0.13) \DeltaBritishColumbia_{t-1} & \text{$w_{t-1}>0.62$}
                                      \end{cases}
                        \ ]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have a spurious space `\ ]`  instead of `\]` and have no definition of `\DeltaCanada`

Comment: Why can you not use the answer posted to your last question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153747/write-this-equation

Comment: I have tried all the answers from my last post but nothing fit well with the suggestions. This is why i put all in a way i will set it in my article. So here i have written the equation as it can be seen really.

Comment: Well please edit the question to fix unrelated errors as in my last comment, you can not expect people to know how to define `\DeltaCanada` , I could define `\newcommand\DeltaCanada{Finland}` and the error would go away but that might not be the definition you want. Then perhaps people could help suggest a good layout.